# javafx 2.0 TitledPane how to change the title text to image+text

Tags: javafx-2

[image]

the default title only contains text, just like the "Apples" title  in the above image.

is that possible to add image in the title.

or

is there a way developer can build a customized TitledPane ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setGraphic` method

```
    TitledPane tp = new TitledPane("hi");
    tp.setGraphic(new Rectangle(10, 10));
```

Comment: that works ! 
thank you ! btw , do you know how to remove the triangle on the left side ?

Comment: Create a css stylesheet with the following style definition and [add it to your scene](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getStylesheets%28%29): .titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button .arrow { -fx-shape: ""; }

Comment: but after  .titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button .arrow { -fx-shape: ""; } it still takes 10px space...  i use  "-fx-spacing :-20;" to make image align left. but the total width is still the same

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can set the graphics via the css property "`-fx-graphic`" as well.

See [Oracle Defintion for JFX and CSS, here for elements of type Labeled](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled).

To remove the button completely, you could either

- set `tp.setCollabsible(false);` or
- use the `.titled-pane` CSS class to set the property "`-fx-collapsible`" to false.

See [Here (same side as above, but for TitledPane)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#titledpane).